# Ionic 4 Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error. when calling api on real device

Tags: http, ionic-framework, post

I have an ionic 4 application which calls a .NET Core backend api.
It works correctly on chrome browser, but when I run apk on android device, the response is:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

regarding to header I appended these options:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" , 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH, CONNECT"  
       }) 
};
```

I have already installed plugin:
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

and using HttpClient from "@angular/common/http"

***My API hosted remotely, no ssl certificate used !***

I googled all solutions, but none of them solve my problem

Comment: Angular HTTP is not working properly on real devices. Try to use native HTTP plugin instead https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could resolve problem after two days hardwork  !
I migrated API calling from '@angular/common/http' to native http '@ionic-native/http/ngx'
with this header:

```
        // create headers data
        const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", 
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
          "cache-control": "no-cache", 
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH, CONNECT",  
          };
```

The cons for me, For now on I have to test on a real device.

Comment: @angular/common/http will work in Ionic 4 app , but you have to add one line in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: can you tell deatiled .. how i can fix this issue

Comment: @angular/common/http work on real device. Just add <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" /> to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @AlexeyZheleznyakov now i have nativeStorageError code 2

Comment: @van9petryk I think nativeStorageError code 2 not linked with @angular/common/http

Answer (score 21):

I faced the same issue, the following were my conditions:

- My Ionic 4 app working fine on Chrome but when I run it on emulator it gave me the *"Unknown error"* issue.
- My backend was Laravel 6.
- I am on a Mac using Android Studio and Visual Studio code.
- I was trying to call an API on the server.

I tried many way to resolve the issue. I was sure it is not a CORs issue since I have taken care of it.

So how can you fix something like that. You have to just add one line, i.e.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in this tag:

```xml
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

in your manifest file i.e.,

```
[yourProject]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: refer to this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: Thank you!!! You saved me many hours of debugging :)

Comment: You saved my lot of hours, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Certain things I would advice you to check:

> 1)  CORS enable at your server side
>
> 2) If your APIs is not https, make sure android webview is not blocking the traffic. Enforce enable of `cleartextTraffic`, which is disabled by default. Add a security config in your app like below. Setup reference [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/livereload-err-cleartext-not-permitted/163487/10)

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: I did that but no change, in browser is ok but in mobile still not working

Comment: in server:             // call configure oAuth
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            // create new instance of http configuration
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            // register web api configuration
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            
            // allow all cors
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            // use web api for app
            app.UseWebApi(config);

Comment: any other advice?

Comment: I did this and did not work AT ALL, in fact, my app which had never had more than 1 failure or ANR, now has a report with 62 failures affecting 11 users.

Comment: Did not help in my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
4 Possible Case 

1: Check your Internet connection 
2: Cors must be enabled from Backend
3:   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" must be added in config.xml and android manifest file in the resource folder

4: Backend IP or domain should be configured in /resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I added the cors conditions in my API and changed the WebViewer vension, but the error remained. You can solve it by modifying the ip of the server where my api runs.

/resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

Answer (score 0):

localhost does not support any android app. If you try to hit API with localhost then, android considers localhost 0.0.0.0:

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the API used SSL but has expired. No more issues after they renew the SSL.

Answer (score -1):

Below change is finally work for me
changing the API endpoint from http://localhost:7071/data to http://192.168.1.11:7071/data,
where 192.168.1.11 is the local IP address of the host.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, the following were my conditions:

My Ionic 6 and capacitor app working fine on Chrome but when I run it on emulator it gave me the "Unknown error" issue.

My backend was AWS.

I am on a Mac using Android Studio and Visual Studio code.
I was trying to call an API on the server.
I tried many way to resolve the issue. I was sure it is not a CORS issue since I have taken care of it.

So how can you fix something like that. You have to just add one line, i.e.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in this tag:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j2Gd.png)
in your manifest file i.e.,

```
[yourProject]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

If you are using ionic and cordova better to add usecleartraffic  in side config.xml if you are using cordova, below is sample taken from a working app.

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
```

and you are good to go.